# How to send get request when table head of a html page is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, http

This is the html table and it has many table headers like s.no., first name, etc. So whenever any header is clicked I want to send a get request with the some values different for each headers.

[image]

The following is the table code I have used.

```
    <table class = "table" style = "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id = "s.no.">S.No.</th>
                <th id = "fname">First Name</th>
                <th id = "lname">Last Name</th>
                <th id = "email">Email</th>
                <th id = "password">Password</th>
                <th id = "dob">Date of Birth</th>
                <th id = "gender">Gender</th>
                <th id = "hobbies">Hobbies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for candidate in candidates%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{candidate.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.fname}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.lname}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.password}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.dob}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{candidate.hobbies}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _“with the some values different for each headers”_? And where is your attempt to perform a GET request?

Comment: Please elaborate.. Also add some code that you have tried

Comment: Also tag the framework/server you need. Sounds to me like you just want to search google for "php ajax html table"

Comment: 1) use query selector to get all `th` tags, 2) loop over them and add a `click` event listener, 3) in the listener set the "different values" as you need, based on which tag it is and 4) send the request

Comment: @SebastianSimon plz ommit "the" between "with" and "some". So I will return some sort of values as per my wish to give server some command accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you

```js
let tableHead = document.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];

tableHead.addEventListener("click", function(){
  httpRequest = (url, method = 'GET') => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.status === 200) { resolve(xhr.responseText); }
        else { reject(new Error(xhr.responseText)); }
      };
      xhr.send();
    });}  
});
```

```html
    <table class = "table" style = "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id = "s.no.">S.No.</th>
                <th id = "fname">First Name</th>
                <th id = "lname">Last Name</th>
                <th id = "email">Email</th>
                <th id = "password">Password</th>
                <th id = "dob">Date of Birth</th>
                <th id = "gender">Gender</th>
                <th id = "hobbies">Hobbies</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: This js code is not working as the get request is not being sent to server and also the table headers are not responding to any sort of click on them. In total the table headers are not made clickable even after adding this js code.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra the click is working fine you can try to console.log('something') and you will see the click event is working

Comment: Yes the click is working it can be seen on console, actually the get request is not going to server for any click.